# Is it possible to assign multiple commands to a single hotkey? (bash, xterm)

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

Back in the day, if my cursor was in the middle of a really long shell command I'd just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get myself a new command prompt.

Then I learned about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>C</kbd> and life was good. Unfortunately those sequences are a little awkward for me, so now I'd like to map one shortcut to reset the entire line with one sequence.

Is it possible to map something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> so it performs those two commands? I checked the variables in `man bash` and found `kill-whole-line` but I'm not sure how to implement it in my .bashrc -- or if that's even what I need (seems like it is).

ED: I learned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> might not be the best choice because [it's a gateway to other bash shortcuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29#Keyboard_shortcuts), so I went with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following line into `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-x": kill-whole-line
```

Or, add the following into your `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind '"\C-x": kill-whole-line'
```

To see all the possible bindings and which are in effect, run

```
bind -p
```

You might need to unbind the combinations that start with `\C-x`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to assign multiple commands to a single hotkey directly. Normally one would do following in the `~/.inputrc`

```
"\C-x": some-readline-command (eg. kill-whole-line)
```

However, you can do following to map hotkey to any sequence of input (where you can reference already bound commands by their hotkeys too and hence execute them)

```
"\C-x": "\C-knew text"
```

**Note:**
Actually above wouldn't work because `\C-x` is by default bound as leader key for other bindings (eg. `\C-x\C-u` for `undo` in `emacs` mode). You have to unbind all of those to make pure `\C-x` do something.